# How to change APP settings in UIAutomation script before tests run?

Tags: instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

In my app I determine which database schema and server address i wanna use in app (configurations are inside system settings of the device). On app startup i load some data from DB.

App makes queries to/from DB so I don't want to mistakenly run tests on wrong DB.

Is there any solution to change these settings before UI tests (prepare correct app settings)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why couldn't you set the database schema and server address as part of each test?

Comment: YES, at that moment i achieve it by setting properties of app at beggining of tests (before i don't know how to set it in tests) `UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().setPreferencesValueForKey( "MY_GUITEST_SC‌​HEMA","MY_USERDEFAULTS_PROPERTY")`

Comment: OK, are you saying the problem is solved by this?

Comment: Yes, test launch by xcodeBot on server with a charm :)